# Restrict browser plugin usage to specific servers?

Tags: security, browser, plugins

For a new banking application we are currently discussing the details of a browser plugin installed on client PCs for accessing smartcard readers.

A question that came up was: Is there a way to restrict the usage of this plugin to a specified list of domains? It should prevent any third-party-site to use the plugin just by serving some <embed/object>-Tag.

The solution should be basically browser-independent. 
It may include cryptography if neccessary, but should only result in moderate implementation overhead in the plugin code.

Ideas, anyone?

---

I know there exists a MS solution called [SiteLock](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=43cd7e1e-5719-45c0-88d9-ec9ea7fefbcb&displaylang=en), but that's only IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came up with this idea: (described for one server)

The plugin carries a public key A. The plugin creator issues a certificate to the server's public key B. The server starts the plugin within a HTML-page and provides these parameters:

- several allication sepcific parameters
- the certificate
- a digital signature

Then the plugin will start and first of all perform these checks:

- verify the certificate with the public key delivered within the plugin
- verify the signature with the public key from the certificate
- if verification was OK then proceed, else terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code the list of authorized domains into the plugin itself.

Alternatively, you could expose a web service which will deliver a list of authorized domains.  The plugin could make a call to your web service when instantiated to determine whether it can be started or not.